# Python Reopening file after writing it

Tags: python, html, file

I've already managed to create a program called write.py that accepts information via "post" from HTML and writes this information (only ever one line long) to a file called infoLog.ssv. Now I'm trying to create another .py program that will both append this document with another line of text, and then read everything that is contained within infoLog.ssv and print it to the screen. I seem to be running into issues when my program tries to open the appended file. I've checked and yes, my program is successfully appending the document, but it seems to just stop working when I reopen it.

```
f=open("infoLog.ssv","a")
strValueQuestion=str(question)
f.write("\n"+strValueQuestion)
f.close()
print "Successfully added"
f1=open("infoLog.ssv","r")
f1.close()
sys.stdout.flush()
print "It never prints this..."
```

As you can see, while attempting to debug, I only open and close the file now and even still it never prints the last print statement.

Comment: What is `f1`? You don't show where it is defined.

Comment: The line `f1.open("infoLog.ssv","r")` should give an error. You probably meant `f1 = open("infoLog.ssv", "r")`.

Comment: Oops - that was just a typo. I have fixed it

Comment: and the `sys.stdout.flush` is a typo too, right? Should be `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. Well this is embarrassing. It's fixed. Hopefully that's it for typos

Answer (score 3):

Check your logs, it is probably giving an error in the line `f1.open("infoLog.ssv", "r")`.

If you want to print the file contents, what you mean is probably:

```
with open("infoLog.ssv","r") as f1:
    print f1.read()
    sys.stdout.flush()
    print "It should prints this... =)"
```

Note that [if you use the `with` statement, you don't need to explicitly close the file descriptor](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: Is there any way to read AND write to a file at the same time? I'm a beginner to python :S

Comment: @Jerler You usually just read or just write to a file. Can you tell exactly what is the error? Have you checked if the line is actually being written to the file? Double check if the file have write permissions and all that.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently 'r+' or 'w+' allow you to both read and write to a file at the same time.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files